# How does Kubernetes does ensure dynamic deployment ? how can it change the data path?

Tags: networking, dynamic, deployment, kubernetes

For the first part of the question, I want to know how k8s may deploy a new pod dynamically and make it functional.

For the second part, let's suppose that we have two pods (A and B) that communicate together, so if we deploy a new pod (let C) How can Kubernetes change the datapath by forcing A and B to communicate via C?

I'll be so thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how k8s may deploy a new pod dynamically and make it functional.

Generally, through a workload controller like a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/), etc.

> let's suppose that we have two pods (A and B) that communicate together, so if we deploy a new pod (let C) How can Kubernetes change the datapath by forcing A and B to communicate via C?

Generally, it's done through service discovery with [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). There are other alternatives like using something like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) which can also use DNS and/or it has its own [catalog](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html)